# Docker Volume on Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-pvc

I am trying to deploy a docker image on a kubernetes cluster.

What I want to achieve on the cluster is the same output as I achieve when I run this command locally (The output will be some generated files)

```
sudo docker run \
  --env ACCEPT_EULA="I_ACCEPT_THE_EULA" \
  --volume /my-folder:/opt/data \
  --volume /my-folder:/opt/g2 \
  test/installer:3.0.0
```

What I have created for the deployment on the kubernetes side is this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: default
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: test
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: nfs-volume
          nfs:
            # URL for the NFS server
            server: SERVER_HOSTNAME
            path: PATH
      containers:
      - name: test-container
        image: DOCKER_IMAGE
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "1000m"
          limits:
            memory: "2Gi"
            cpu: "2000m"
        env:
          - name: ACCEPT_EULA
            value: "I_ACCEPT_THE_EULA"
        volumeMounts:
          - name: nfs-volume
            mountPath: /var/nfs
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
```

The problem that I have is wrt/ to these two arguments, I can not understand how to perform the related actions on the k8 side. Any suggestions ?

```
--volume /my-folder:/opt/data
--volume /my-folder:/opt/g2
```

Currently I get errors like:
cp: cannot create directory '/opt/test': Permission denied

Comment: Where is the `/my-folder` directory; is it the NFS mount?  It looks like you already have syntax to mount that NFS volume on `/var/nfs` inside the container, which is conceptually quite similar to the Docker `--volume` options you show.

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing what features you need from the two volumes.
Should they be empty at startup? Should they contain some data?
Should be unique to each pod or shared among pods of the same type?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: default
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: test
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: my-folder
          hostPath:
            path: /my-folder
      containers:
      - name: test-container
        image: test/installer:3.0.0
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "1000m"
          limits:
            memory: "2Gi"
            cpu: "2000m"
        env:
          - name: ACCEPT_EULA
            value: "I_ACCEPT_THE_EULA"
        volumeMounts:
          - name: nfs-volume
            mountPath: /var/nfs
          - name:  my-folder
            mountPath: /opt/data
          - name:  my-folder
            mountPath: /opt/g2
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
```